# Why do I get this error "No product matches the given query."?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

When i add `product` to my `home` function in views.py I got this error :

```
No product matches the given query.
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25jXz.png)

Why do I get this error?

views:

```
class productviewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset=product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = productSerializer 

    def create(self, request):
        serialized = productSerializer(data=request.data, many=True)
        if serialized.is_valid():
            serialized.save()
            return Response(serialized.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serialized._errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    @action (detail=False , methods=['post']) 
    def delete(self,request):
        product.objects.all().delete()
        return Response('success')


def home(request ):
    p=get_object_or_404(product,pk=1)
    return render(request,'home.html',{'p':p})

def foods(request):
    
    return render(request,'foods.html',{'p':category.objects.all()})
```

models:

```
class category(models.Model):

    name=models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class product(models.Model):
     
    category = models.ForeignKey(category, related_name='products',on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    image=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    description=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    price=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    buy=models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

urls:

```
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework import routers
from quick.views  import productviewset 
from quick import views
from django.contrib import admin


urlpatterns = [
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
    path('',views.home),
    path('foods',views.foods),
    path('admin/',admin.site.urls),
     
]
```

Comment: The error is beacuse the `id=1` in the `Product` model doesn't exist in the database which is given in the `get_object_or_404` , maybe you have deleted it, try another id which exist and you'll not see error.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

**views.py**

```py
def home(request, id):
    p=get_object_or_404(product, id=id)
    return render(request,'home.html',{'p':p})
```

**urls.py**

```py
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('<int:id>/', views.home, name='name'),
]
```

> `Note`: Always add `/` at the end of every route.

> `Note`: Models in django are written in *PascalCase* not *smallcase*, it will be better if you change it from <s>`category`</s> and <s>`product`</s> to `Category` and `Product` respectively.

> Class based views are also written in *PascalCase*, you can change it to `ProductViewSet`.

Comment: It is `<int:id>/` and always add `/` at the end of every route.